# VSCode extension: code completion of custom language only triggers when invoked

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm the author of the [Language support for CloudFormation templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keyboardDrummer.vscode-cloudformation) extension. It provides code completion, but right now this is, against my intention, only triggered when invoked (when pressing ctrl+space). I suspect this is because the identifiers in the language are encapsulated in quotes, and VSCode is treating them as strings. However, when I set "strings" to true in "editor.quickSuggestions", the code completion still only works when invoked.

I've tried changing the syntax highlighting grammar so it no longer registers anything as a string, but that did not work. I've also tried specifying a 'wordPattern' in the language configuration that included the quotes, but without luck. ([Here's](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide) the documentation on word patterns)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The wordPattern I had specified was "[a-zA-Z]*", so when typing "ba[cursorPosition]", VS Code would not trigger autocompletion because it would think "ba" is a word and the cursor is in the middle of the word, at which point apparently it does not trigger autocompletion.

Changing the wordPattern to "[a-zA-Z]* resolved the issue.